# Add names to a list without splitting in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a program where a user copy pastes a list of names seperated by spaces & python saves it as a list.

However, while using list.extend it splits every name into alphabets. How can I fix it so it saves each name as a string.

How can I solve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you please `edit` your question and add what you already tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

```
import re
input = "program where a user copy pastes a list of names seperated"
output = re.split(" ", input)
```

Result:

```
['program', 'where', 'a', 'user', 'copy', 'pastes', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'names', 'seperated']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings have the `split` function, that split by white space:

```py
s = "foo bar baz"
s.split()
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```